Can I sue for lack of amenity advertised and promised in my apartment?
When we picked the apartment, the website said laundry is in every unit, and upon signing the lease we were told the broken units were moved out and we would have a new install within the first week of living here. It's now been almost a year with no laundry in our unit and it has been an added expense every week since. Do I have legal ground with my complex?

Read the lease - that is what you contractually are due. Nothing more, unless it is required by law.

If your landlord broke the lease, you can sue for damages
First, you need to determine if what you remember being said about the laundry is actually in the lease. If it is, great, if it isn’t things get tricky.
In general, representations made before entering a written contract are irrelevant. People adopt and abandon all sorts of positions during negotiations so the law accepts that what got written down is what the parties actually agreed. That said, there’s a whole area of law about missrepresntion that could be relevant but it is super fact-dependent.
Second, you need to quantify your loss. For example, if you had to use a laundromat, the cost of that and the cost of travelling to and from it (but not the cost of your time) would be the starting point for your damages. You can also try to quantify the value of the loss of amenity. Even over a year, this is unlikely to be a significant amount, but lawsuits are not always brought for pure commercial reasons.
